# Parametric equation and limits

Tags: integration

I have a fundamental doubt .Suppose , we are integrating a double integral in X-Y plane , with parametric equation reducing to $$ r= a \cos{t} $$.Then , I am of the view that limits of t should ideally vary from -π/2 to +π /2 .But , there are many text books ,taking the limits for t  ( while doing the double integral ) as 0 to π  .Is it justified .At π ,radius vector is negative ,so how can limit vary till π.Please ,if anyone can justify.

Comment: It depends on what region are you integrating. The limits can't be decided just by the function. We need some more information.

Comment: We are integrating in entire region of circle .

Comment: Can t be ever equal to π ?.At π circle won't be there .Circle is there in 1st  and 4th quadrant.

Comment: Can you upload the exact question?

Comment: Ok so question is calculate the volume bounded by Sphere x^2 +y^2 + z^2 =a^2 and Cylinder x^2 +y ^2 = 2ax .Please try to solve it in parametric form .

Answer (score 0):

For your particular example, i.e. the volume enclosed by a sphere and a cylinder, the parametric integral should take the form

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin\theta d\theta\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} d\phi\int_0^{f(\theta,\phi)}r^2dr$$

The range for either angle integration is $\pi$.

Comment: Quanto ,please if you evaluate it completely .I am still having some doubts .

Comment: The actual integration is quite involved due to overlapping between the two shapes. I'll work it out when I get a chance.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3321156/limits-of-integration-for-parametric-equation.Just now i have added solution to that question .Please visit the link .I have explicitly mentioned my exact doubt there .Please see if you can help me out .

Comment: Result in the link does not seem right, which ought to have $\pi$.

Comment: Its a printing error in last step .Anyways , satisfactory answer has been given by Hans.Thanks